# Single page with menu over the content

Tags: css, single-page-application, singlepage

I'm building a single page website and would like to put the fixed menu over the scroller content:

http://jsfiddle.net/VFQF8/

But using the fixed position, I can't keep the menu over the content. Any idea?

```
#nav {
    left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwHDX/)

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    width: inherit;
}
#section-1{
    margin-top:200px;
}
```